# Magento help - cant access site or admin panel due to warning: failed opening messages and fatal errer message

Tags: php, magento

I just tried to upgrade Magento using the MagentoConnect Manager.

I now don't have access to my site or the admin panel. I get this message when I try to access the site

```
Warning: include(/homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Zend_Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Zend_Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php5.4') in /homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php on line 247
```

and this message when i try to access the admin panel:

```
Warning: include(/homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Zend_Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Zend_Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php5.4') in /homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /homepages/21/d527676353/htdocs/wtw2014/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php on line 24
```

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by checking if the directory ../lib/Zend and make sure the log file is within there. If not, double check your previous site if available and see if it's still there.

If it "is" there, make sure directory permissions are set correctly.I.e the log.php file should have it's permissions set to 644. (Read and Write for owner, Read for group and read for public)  This is where I would start